# Change class onClick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation that shows an active state using class="active".  When a link is clicked, I need to add the "active" class to to the clicked link, and remove the "active" class from all other links.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="referNav">
<div id="referLink1"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="changeClass();" class="active"></a></div>
<div id="referLink2"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="changeClass();" class=""></a></div>
<div id="referLink3"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="changeClass();" class=""></a></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changeClass() {
    $('#referNav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

And you should also bind the function in javacript like so:

```
$('#referNav a').on('click', changeClass);
```

That way, as Travis J points out in the comments, `$(this)` will reference the correct object.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJgRQ/)

Comment: Note that as this function will not be an event, `this` will be a reference to the window.

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to need to do is make a function called `changeClass` which will look for `class="active"` and then remove that class. Then assign the class name `active` to the element which was just clicked. It would be beneficial to pass the element being clicked to the function so you will know which element were clicked. Otherwise you can use the global object `event` and see what the current `targetElement` was.

I am reluctant to just show a solution because this type of question is not encouraged. People should do their own work. However, since this is a simple situation: **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xkUb8/)**

```
$("div[id^=referLink] a").click(function(){
 $('#referNav .active').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
 $('#referNav').on('div','click',functin(e){
    $(e.target).closest('div[class^="referLink"]').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).closest('div').find('a').addClass('active');
    });
```